# A simple function equation in calculus-1 course

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Here is a homework question:


$f^2(\ln x)-2xf(\ln x)+x^2\ln x=0,\ f(0)=0,\ f(x)=$？


I don't know how to solve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the following way:


$\text{Let}\ \ln x=t\Rightarrow x=e^t\Rightarrow f^2(t)-2e^tf(t)+te^{2t}=0\Rightarrow f(t)=e^t(1\pm\sqrt{1-t})$


$f(0)=0\Rightarrow f(t)=e^t(1-\sqrt{1-t})\Rightarrow f(x)=e^x(1-\sqrt{1-x}),\ x\le1$.

Comment: could you explain the last $\Rightarrow$ step please?

Comment: It's not special meaning. Just change the variable because a function has the same form using any variable.